# looking for a mic that would pick up the low end sound of a gunshot. so far i have a  

Tags: microphone, sound-effects-recording, gear

looking for a microphone that would pick up the low end sound of a gunshot. so far i have a 
- rode ntg-3 
- sennheiser mkh-416 
- oktava mk-012

i would like to spent less then $900

thanks guys
~reN

Answer (score 2):

just throw up an omni-directional mic somewhere close to the gun. few other patterns can get you as even a low end pickup as a high quality omni.

Answer (score 1):

The 416 is one of my favorite mics on guns.  You can get great low end with it, but placement is critical (as with any mic).  Keep in mind that the location will also have an effect on your sound.  The three mics that I must have when I record guns; 416, RSM191, and MKH800.  Of those 3, the 416 is the best at the low end stuff.

Beyond the 416, if you are really only looking at picking up low end, I recommend you find a used Crown SASS.  Those are great for low end punch, but you really need to work with them and learn how best to place them as I've found they can be pretty picky.

I'll add that I've never had good luck using bass drum mics on guns.

Answer (score 1):

get a 2nd dynamic mic, a shure 57 , get a big plastic garbage can, fill it with water, protect the mic with a condom put the mic in the water, set the gain very low.

the set up will have to be a feet aside from the gun.

great Lfe.

Record the 2 mics on different tracks

Comment: Gotta try this one in our next session! Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

My go to for getting good Mid Low Punch is MKH418S into an FR2 recorder - location and gain settings are the key though. Also if you are after Low end, the height of the Mic above the ground is crucial. Like @Chuck Russom already mentioned I've also heard great things from the Crown SASS but don't actually have experience myself.

One Mic I always take with me when recording loud stuff is a D112 usually running into a cheap recorder like a H4. I've had reasonable results placing it under the shooter if they are standing, if not I try to place it where I think Bass will collect - i.e. in a corner somewhere or under a big rock. It's a bit hit and miss even to the extent that some guns sound great and others not on the same session without moving the mic.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the 418s. Super great mic!

Answer (score 0):

I just writing you should try an AKG D112. Dynamic, works with high SPL and tailored to work with lower frequencies such as a kick drum.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Sennheiser MD21. This is a dynamic omnidirectional mike. Experiment with placing it as close as possible to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for your input, it was all very informative.

~reN

Answer (score 0):

For low end stuff I would use close proximity micing (below the gun) either Beta-52A or D112 dynamic kick drum mics. Works every time and you´ll get awesome low end. Remember to listen and check the position before starting the actual session, moving the mic even few inches makes a lot of difference how much bottom end you get.